# "Quick Fix..." in Visual Studio for Mac isn't very helpful

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've recently switched from Xamarin to Visual Studio for Mac. There are a few differences but mostly it's just rebranding.

I'm not sure if Microsoft removed something, but it appears that quick fix does a few things differently.

The thing that I'm particularly interested in is the ability to convert `var` to **explicit type**. With Xamarin there was no problem, but with Visual Studio, quick-fix shows the following:

- To protected
- To internal
- To protected internal
- To public

Anyone know if there's a setting for this somewhere?

Also, I'm running it with Unity extension. However, disabling it doesn't do much for quick-fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Code Style suggestion. It will give you 3 dots under the `var` keyword and a suggestion to change it.

[image: Options]

I'm not sure how this looks like on OSX and if all the options are out there, but [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/12/15/code-style-configuration-in-the-vs2017-rc-update/) is a blog post about Code Style Configuration for VS2017. [Here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/12518454-add-quickaction-to-refactor-var-to-implicit-type) is also someone else who was looking for a solution to the same problem and posted it as a suggestion to UserVoice.

Also the [Roslynator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=josefpihrt.RoslynatorRefactorings2017) extension has a refactoring setting for [`ChangeVarToExplicitType`](https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/docs/refactorings/ChangeVarToExplicitType.md) that you might want to try out if all else fails.